# Excel: Converting between data layouts

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the situation as show below. There are groups of rows. Above each group is a small "header" describing a data field that all the rows in the group have in common.
I want to create a pivot table of everything and include that field (GroupID), hence I want the second version of the table.
Is there a way of doing this short of recording a macro?
Or is there perhaps a way of creating the pivot table directly?

**I have:**

```
GroupID
4

Name      Email       Likes   Dislikes
herpina   something   Cake    Excel
derpina   something   Cake    Excel

GroupID
5

Name      Email       Likes   Dislikes
roflmao   something   Cake    Hmm
roflomg   something   Baking  test
testtttt  something   Sleep   22

GroupID
1

Name      Email       Likes   Dislikes
OAG       something   OAB     N/A
OAB       something   N/A     N/A
```

**Desired:**

```
Name      Email       Likes   Dislikes  GroupID
herpina   something   Cake    Excel     4
derpina   something   Cake    Excel     4
roflmao   something   Cake    Hmm       5
roflomg   something   Baking  test      5
testtttt  something   Sleep   22        5
OAG       something   OAB     N/A       1
OAB       something   N/A     N/A       1
```

This sample input is also located at https://dl.dropbox.com/u/736090/Book1.xlsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the macro as short as possible

- open Excel and press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>
- insert the code below into *sheet1* or where ever your data is
- close VBA editor and press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> and ececute the macro

  ```
  Sub deletelines()    
    Range("A4:D4").Copy
    Range("A1").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    For i = 2 To Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
      c = Cells(i - counter, 1)
      if IsNumeric(c) And c <> "" Then groupID = c
      If c = "" Or c = "Name" Or c = "GroupID" Or IsNumeric(c) Then
        Rows(i - counter).Delete
        counter = counter + 1
      Else
        Cells(i - counter, 5) = groupID
      End If
    Next i   
  End Sub
  ```

---

Since this is a Q&A site, I describe the code. That way it may be helpful for others who can easily adapt and customize the code.

- Line 1+14: starts and ends a macro (subroutine)
- Line 2+3: copy the range [A4:D4] and insert it before [A1]. This forms your header row
- `Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row` determines the last used cell. In your eample its 22
- Line 4: is a loop which starts at 2 and ends at 22. The `i` is used as row index
- Line 5: saves first cell of current line. General syntax is `cells(rownumber,columnnumber)`
  Attention: Since we delete rows, we have to subtract how many lines we already have deleted.
- Line 6: Look if `c` is a number and save it as our currect groupID until we find another number
- Line 7: Is a condition which checks if the current cell value is "Name", "GroupID", blank or a Number.
- Line 8: If the condition is true, this deletes the whole line
- Line 9: If the condition is true, this counts up our *howmanydeletedlines* counter
- Line 10-12: If the condition is false, this has to be a good data row we want to preserve
- Line 13: loops to the next `i` which stands for our current line

Comment: It's a start, but not quite there. Please have a look at the sample input at https://dl.dropbox.com/u/736090/Book1.xlsx - and do let me know if you need it in another format.

Comment: I edited my answer. I tested it with your book1.xlsx and it worked for me.